# Are the RandomForest and Ranger libraries the same?

Tags: r, time-series, random-forest

After being stuck in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72683492/how-to-model-time-series-data-into-random-forest-error-incorrect-number-of-di) question, I found another way to perform random forest.

I'm trying to compare a normal random forest model (train & test/predicted) and time series data. My data have date columns, my target variable plus another predictor. I used the `train()` function from the ranger package for my target variable with the predictor. Based on my understanding ranger is a random forest.

However, after converting my data to time series (ts) I got error when I ran `train()` from ranger on my time series data, but it worked when I ran the `randomForest()` function.

Are ranger and randomForest the same?
I know in my case if I applied random forest and `train()` from ranger I won't get the same results because one is time series and one have more variables but If I applied the same dataset to `randomForest()` and `train()` will I get the same result?

Answer (score 9):

They are different implementations of the same algorithm. As random forest utilises [bagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) and bagging is inherently stochastic, we cannot guarantee that they will give exactly the same result. That said, if one downright errs, this is a coding issue rather than a statistical one.

Answer (score 8):

The title of the paper introducing it is literally

> [ranger: A Fast Implementation **of Random Forests** for High Dimensional Data in C++ and R](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04409)

(highlighting by myself). But as said by
usεr11852, random forest is randomized and there may be implementational differences, so exactly the same results are not guaranteed.